# django template system, calling a function inside a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to call a function from my model at a template such  as:

```
class ChannelStatus(models.Model):
 ..............................
 ..............................

    def get_related_deltas(self,epk):
        mystring = ""
        if not self.get_error_code_delta(epk):
            return mystring
        else:
            for i in self.get_listof_outage():
                item = i.error_code.all()
                for x in item:
                    if epk == x.id:
                        mystring= mystring +" "+str(i.delta())
        return mystring
```

And when I want to call this from the template:
assume  while rendering, I pass channel_status_list as

```
channel_status_list = ChannelStatus.objects.all()

{% for i in channel_status_list %}
  {{ i.get_related_deltas(3) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work, I am able to call a function that consumes nothing, but couln't find what to do if it has parameter(s)

Cheers

Answer (score 97):

You can't call a function with parameters from the template. You can only do this in the view. Alternatively you could write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), which might look like this:

```
@register.filter
def related_deltas(obj, epk):
    return obj.get_related_deltas(epk)
```

So now you can do this in the template:

```
{% for i in channel_status_list %}
  {{ i|related_deltas:3 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hello, thanks alot for the backup! I am getting "related_deltas requires 1 arguments, 0 provided" error. I am doing exactly as you said.
Regards

Comment: Hmm, that should work. Can you post the full traceback (probably somewhere like dpaste.com rather than here)?

Comment: That seems to be a different error, probably caused by a double pipe character in `{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0||add:"5" }}`.

Comment: actually at my template, it is {{ forloop.parentloop.counter0|add:"5" }}, It is really weird it display it as "||".

Comment: I agree with Daniel, this does appear to be an issue with your template.

Comment: Hey guys, where is that related_deltas function defined in the code? I'm getting a Name Error: name 'register' is not defined when i try to put it in my view.

Comment: So you have to create a template tag for every function you want to call with parameters?

Comment: @TylerBrock i get the same error, did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: @FadyKamal too long ago... sorry. I totally forget what I wound up doing.

Comment: @TylerBrock `register` can be used like this: `from django import template` and then
`register = template.Library()`. [see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 42):

If the method doesn't require any arguments, you can use the @property decorator and access it normally in the template.

```
class ChannelStatus(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def function_you_want_as_property(self):
        mystring = ""
        ...
```

Comment: Which is not the case in the question, also Django use properties or methods seamlessly as long as they don't have any arguments.

Comment: `@property` not needed

Comment: Can you add an example of use in a template?

Answer (score 10):

For > 1 argument, use [simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

```
@register.simple_tag
def related_deltas(obj, epk, second_arg):
    return obj.get_related_deltas(epk, second_arg)
```

Template:

```
{% for i in channel_status_list %}
  {% related_deltas i 3 4 %}
{% endfor %}
```

*(Note the change of syntax from `{{` to `{%`)*

Can take **positional** parameters (e.g. `related_deltas i 3 second_arg=4 debug=true`).

Answer (score 6):

If you find that there are too many properties running around everywhere or you have a template filter for every other method that you write, another solution was suggested on IRC thanks @FunkyBob.  It's a little well, erm, funky but it is nice in certain cases.

```
  class MethodProxy(object):
        """For consolidating into 1 method the calling of methods with various single args
        (suitable dictionary keys)

        class MyModel(models.Model):
            ...

            def magic(self, value):
                # Free the ponies

            def thing(self):
                return MethodProxy(self.magic)

        # Usage
        >>> m = MyModel()
        ...
        >>> m.thing['value'] == m.magic('value')

        # template
        {{ m.thing.value }}

        """

        def __init__(self, method):
            self.method = method
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            return self.method(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define a property.
See https://web.archive.org/web/20160407103752/http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2008/aug/11/the-python-property-builtin/ .

You write your function that can do pretty much anything you want.
You make it a read only property.
You call the property from the template.

Et voilà !!!!

Comment: this is pointless... the Django template system already allows to to call methods as if they were properties (as long as the method does not take any args)