# Passing named arguments to functions in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have in my Django controller a function that is called as follows:

```
trip.driverTrip.filter(status='pending')
```

What it will be the equivalent of calling this in a template. If I just want to call the filter function, the following will suffice:

```
{{trip.driverTrip.filter}}
```

But is there a way to pass it arguments ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no controllers in Django ... Do you mean `a view` ;) ?

The equivalent in a template would be :

```
{{ trip.driverTrip|filter:"pending" }}
```

However, for this to work, your function `filter` has to be registered as a template filter, and 'loaded' in your template. You cannot just call any function (or method) like this. Plus, if you do this, assuming that the preceding conditions are fulfilled it means that you pass `trip.driverTrip` as the first argument to `filter`, and `"pending"` is an additional argument.

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: Yes, view, sorry, and yes, it does answer my question perfectly :). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[django template system, calling a function inside a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333189/django-template-system-calling-a-function-inside-a-model/1333277#1333277) explains, you can't do it directly, but it that site also suggests a workaround.