# Since Django discourages passing arguments to functions in templates, what is encouraged instead?

Tags: python, django

I understand that in Django, the template language is purposely neutered to prevent too much computation in display code. It means that, ideally, for every situation where users might feel compelled to do computation, there's a more proper alternative. Either a tag or filter that does the trick, or something hopefully straightforward in the view. Any annoyances that don't fit into here are hopefully rare.

But I've found a common case that is rather annoying, and either Django has a better way to do this that I haven't thought of, or they ought to see the light here and move the line a little bit on computing within a template in a near future release (as they did with if statement parameters, for instance):

I have a queryset of items. I need to display them somehow, but what I display depends not only on the state of the object, but also other independent things (usually who is logged in). So adding a function to the model won't help.

What I've been doing so far is turning the queryset into a list or tree structure (depending on the task), and adding a "view_extra" attribute to each one. view_extra is a dictionary where I generally stick in values that are dependent on things like who is logged in. Apart from being a hassle, it also destroys the laziness of the queryset. I guess I could go so far as to make a generator, but obviously this is not what the Django developers had in mind for us to do.

I should probably try queryset annotation more, but I don't know how well that would work in some more complicated cases. Plus, no good in a tree or list-within-list structure scenario (queryset of items with members that are further querysets I need to iterate over).

I could register a filter, (as suggested here [django template system, calling a function inside a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333189/django-template-system-calling-a-function-inside-a-model/1333277#1333277)) but that is an abuse of filters, right? They are meant to transform text and maybe data, not to be a specific-purpose replacement for something the developers deliberately tried to get us not to do.

Any "proper" way to do this that I don't know about? Am I off base here by suggesting that this is a deficiency of Django's templating system as it stands?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why creating a custom tag or filter is an 'abuse'. As far as I'm concerned, that's exactly what they're for, and I use them for that all the time.

Comment: +1 I agree. I've just started using Django Templates for a side-project (I use Mako for my main project), and while I find it rather cumbersome in some cases, registering a tag isn't really that difficult. You're moving logic into a `code` area, and removing it from display logic.

Comment: But at that point, why don't they let you pass parameters to any member function? Do they just make it more cumbersome to keep us from doing it too much?

Comment: I wouldn't call it abuse either but I agree with @orblivion on this one. Creating a custom tag or filter may be the recommended answer to this problem but most of the time it just introduces unwanted indirection. Your template still has a method call and it still passes a parameter. The only difference is that you are forced to write up a middleman.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Jinja templates](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) would be a good alternative to using Django's templating system in this instance. Apart from the important fact that Jinja allows you to use some level of logic in your templates, Jinja templates and Django templates are almost identical.

This example code taken directly from the Jinja documents looks like it might be the kind of thing you're trying to achieve.

```
{% for comment in models.comments.latest(10) %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

To integrate Jinja with Django, you could look at [Coffin](https://github.com/dcramer/coffin)