# Calling html from template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm bulding a website in Django 1.3

One of my views is a complex HTML that repeats a lot (  an image gallery with some nested s )

Is there a way to put that logic in a separate file? and call it from django?

Note: Maybe there is a way to do this in HTML and this question may not be related to django.
Note2: I found this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333189/django-template-system-calling-a-function-inside-a-model) which was about calling django's function from a template, using this maybe I could use "render_to_response" function to load the inner HTML.

The purpose of this is to have separated logics for different components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pull the django template code out into a separate file, take a look at [the `{% include %}` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include).

(It seems like you might be asking about something else, but then I'm not real clear on what you want to do...)

Comment: Thanks @Dougal. That was what I looking for, I don't know how I didn't saw it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe there is a way to do this in HTML

If you just want to split your HTML into seperate files and chunks you should use the `{% include %}` tag Dougal mentioned.
However, if you want to include extra logic in your HTML you should turn to [Template Tags and Filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

> Django’s template system comes with a wide variety of built-in tags
>   and filters designed to address the presentation logic needs of your
>   application. Nevertheless, you may find yourself needing functionality
>   that is not covered by the core set of template primitives. You can
>   extend the template engine by defining custom tags and filters using
>   Python, and then make them available to your templates using the {%
>   load %} tag.