# Function with arguments in a template. Django

Tags: django

In my template, I display a list of users a user follows. I would like the user to be able to delete one of the users he follows thanks to a button.
I have a function remove_relationship that deletes a relationship.

Here is the function in my models.py:

```
  class UserProfile(models.Model):
  (...)

      def remove_relationship(self, person):
        Relationship.objects.filter(
            from_person=self, 
            to_person=person).delete()
        return
```

I would like to pass this function into my template:

```
   {% for user in following % }
   <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="remove_relationship"/>
   </form>
   {%endfor%}
```

The thing is that I can't pass argument in my template. So how can I do so that each button deletes the relationship with the right user?

I saw an other question on this topic, abut it looks like it doesn't solve my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333189/django-template-system-calling-a-function-inside-a-model)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as though you are confusing client-side code (JavaScript) with server-side (Django).

To get the relevant user ID submitted you could add an additional hidden field to the form:

```
{% for user in following % }
<form method="post" action="{% url views.remove_relationship %}">
 {% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ user.id }}">
<input type="submit" value="delete" />
</form>
{%endfor%}
```

Then create a `remove_relationship` view that does the deletion on the server side, based on the user id you'll now find in `request.POST['user_id']`

Comment: Thank you. When I do as you say, the relationship is deleted as I want. But it redirects the user to the "remove_relationship" view. I would like the user to stay on the same page. Do you have an idea on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, just return an `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('your original view here'))` from the `remove_relationship` view.

Comment: Or, submit the form via Ajax. But then you'd need some Javascript to post it and remove the now-deleted content from the page.

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error: " Reverse for 'myfile.html' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. " I had to import 'reverse' and I used from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse. Is it correct?

Comment: @JulietteDupuis You need to use the view name such as "views.myview" (i.e. the function name) rather than the template file.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I still get this error: "Reverse for 'myview' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. "

Comment: Ok, the thing is that the view I put in (reverse) uses an url dispatcher. I need to add an argument. I wan't the button to redirect to www.mysite/myview/'a number'/ . So I have to do reverse('myview', args=[the number]). thank you very much for your help