# Call methods in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

My view give me a list or reports and the current user

In my template I wanted to do :

```
{% for report in reports %}
    ...
    {% if current_user.can_edit_report(report) == True %}
       ...
    {% endif %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

But that throw mi a error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(report)' from 'current_user.can_edit_report(report)'
```

Because Django seems not to be able to call a method with parameter in a Template.

So I must do it in the View...

Do you have a idea how to do that properly?

Thanks

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333189/django-template-system-calling-a-function-inside-a-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as commented above, this question has duplicates ([How to call function that takes an argument in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468804/django-template-call-function)).

What you want to do is create a custom template tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) like so...

```
# template
<p>Can Edit: {% can_edit_report user_id report_id %}.</p>

# template_tags.py
from django import template

def can_edit_report(parser, token):
    try:
        # tag_name is 'can_edit_report'
        tag_name, user_id, report_id = token.split_contents()
        # business logic here (can user edit this report?)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        report = Report.objects.get(pk=report_id)
        can_edit = user.can_edit_report(report)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag requires two arguments" % token.contents.split()[0])
    return can_edit
```