# pythons `vars()` function in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

In a template I created for my Django view I pass an extra variable called `Item`.
This `Item` object has a string representation of the value it holds. It kinda looks like this:

```
class Item:
    value = ''
    previous_item = Item

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s > %s' % (value, previous_item)
```

This way you can get a chain of items: `value_x > value_y > value_z`

The problem is that now I want to be able to just print the `vars` of the `Item` object I injected into the template, much like the `vars()` function in Python:

```
>>> item = Item('FooBar', None)
>>> vars(item)
```

In my template I want to do the same:

```
<div>
    {{ item }}. {# prints `value_x > value_y > value_z` #}
    {{ vars item }}  {# should print <Item: value_x, None>  or something like that #}
</div>
```

**Is there a way to do pythons `vars()` in the template?**

#### **Workaround**

So for now I'm using an awful slow approach.
To get the `vars` of the template variable i'm adding the vars to the context myself before rendering the template like this:

```
    ctx = super(MyView, self).get_context(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx['vars'] = vars(self)
    ctx['item_vars'] = vars(self.item)
    return ctx
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1333277/7636315 It discusses how a custom template filter can be used to accomplish that. Is this what u require?

Comment: Well, this is not what I want, but it brought me where I want to go. A temporary registered tag is a way to go I guess. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple solution with the help of [Paandittya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7636315/paandittya) that pointed out another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1333277/7636315), what somewhat looks like what I need in this situation:

```
@register.simple_tag
    def var(value)
        return vars(value)
```

Then in the template, load in the tag and call it:

```
{% load my_tags %}
{% var item %}
```