# How to calculate the total after applying discount in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to calculate the total amount after applying the discount. For that i have made cart.py. But when i call the functions from cart.py in templates.html. It neither display the total amount after discount nor the discounted percentage.

**cart.py** created in cart app

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product
from coupons.models import Coupons

class Cart(object):

def __len__(self):
    return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

def get_total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())


def clear(self):
    del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
    self.session.modified = True
@property
def coupon(self):
    if self.coupon_id:
        return Coupons.objects.get(id=self.coupon_id)
 def get_discount(self):
    if self.coupon:
        return (self.coupon.discount / Decimal('100')) * self.get_total_price()

 def get_total_price_after_discount(self):
    return self.get_total_price() - self.get_discount()
```

**template.html**

```
<tr class="gray2">
     <td colspan="2"> coupon ({{discount}}) % off</td>
     <td colspan="3"></td>
     <td class="num neg"> {{cart.get_discount|floatformat:"2"}}</td>
</tr>
<tr class="total">
                <td>Total</td>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
                <td class="num">{{cart.get_total_price_after_discount|floatformat:"2"}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="divo">
    <p>
        coupon code to apply discount
    </p>
    <form action="{% url 'coupons:apply' %}" method="post">
        {{coupon_apply_form}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="apply" class="btn">
</form>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
@require_POST
def coupon_apply(request):
    now = timezone.now()
    form = CouponApplyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        code = form.cleaned_data['code']
        try:
            coupon = Coupons.objects.get(code__iexact=code,
                                        valid_form__lte=now,
                                        valid_to__gte=now,
                                        active=True)
            request.session['coupon_id'] = coupon.id
        except Coupons.DoesNotExist:
            request.session['coupon_id'] = None

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

This portion of template.html is not displaying. Please if anybody can help me in this regard.

**Note:**

```
  coupon_apply_form = CouponApplyForm()
  context={'cart':cart,'coupon_apply_form':coupon_apply_form}
```

I have wrote this in view.py in carts app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django template system, calling a function inside a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333189/django-template-system-calling-a-function-inside-a-model)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call functions from within your template. Do the calculation in your views, and save the new total to a variable and pass that to your template through the context. If you do need help with the actual coding of what I described let me know. This is however a duplicate question.

Edit: I would recommend asking questions in the future that describe the problem you are having instead of using specifics that are only exact to your question. As an example I would ask (Calling function from Django template does not work) which is very concise even though it looks like a "simple" or maybe "dumb" question. Hopefully this helps you in the future! :)

Comment: thanks for your kind response.Please tell me one more thing, can I do these calculations in model.py and then call it in templates? If yes, should i add context in views.py file? I know i am asking silly questions but please guide me in this regard.